# Visual Studio Command Prompt gives "\Common was unexpected at this time"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I need to run MSBuild from the command line using the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010). It used to work fine. Now when I open the window I get the following error message:

```
\Common was unexpected at this time.
```

Trying to run the `msbuild` command after that fails.

I naturally assumed it was an issue with an unquoted entry in my PATH environment variable, possibly from a recent rogue install. I checked that, but the PATH seems to be kosher.

Digging into the file system, I discovered that the batch file being run by the prompt is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat. I edited that by putting in `ECHO` statements to trace the location of the error. That seemed to point to an error at this line:

```
@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" (
```

If I remove the quotation marks, the error is different: "Files was not expected at this time."

The next 2 lines after this are now:

```
@echo 51
@set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%"
```

I assumed the failing statement was the second line, but the `echo` statement doesn't produce any output, so I don't know how that could be happening.

I am using a 64-bit version of Windows 7.

I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: As you are using 64 bit windows, my guess is that you are referring to the 64 bit bat file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat` and not the 32 bit file as you have mentioned. Unfortunately, I do not have a 64 bit machine to test!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/56bdd445-adc6-46ab-a383-6714bdb2030d/) thread.

My guess is your `PATH` got modified recently and now contains some folder path with quotation marks inside.

HTH

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I removed the quotation marks and it works again. I hadn't tried that based on the assumption that Windows still needs the quotation marks to stop it getting confused with spaces. Looks like that isn't the case any more. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasted 2 days on this and nothing helped! Finally your answer came to rescue! You Rock!

Comment: as simple as that can frustrate us :)

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by examining the PATH. It contained '\r', carriage return!!! and I deleted it.

Comment: I had the same problem but was unable to modify the Path variable using normal processes (Control Panel>System.Advanced...). I was forced to modify it directly in the registry because my path was too long for the Win10 path editor dialog. (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment)

However, once I did that, it works fine. (And it only took 6 hours to figure it out :( )

Comment: Hmm I checked my path variables and there are no single or double quotes or carriage returns. I even double checked by copy pasting the registry value into Notepad++. Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't forget to close and reopen the cmd-console / powershell before running `vcvars32.bat` again, otherwise the the updated environment variables will not take effect and it will keep erroring out!

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that inside of an if block the rval of a variable assignment (%PATH% in my case) contained a parentheses, for example:

```
set var=foo ) got ya

if 1 == 2 (
    set var2=%var%
)
```

Displays "got was unexpected at this time."

I found the answer here: [Batch file variable with spaces and parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075799/batch-file-variable-with-spaces-and-parentheses). Which is to use the extended syntax of set. For example:

```
set "var2=%var%"
```

This does not add quotes and does not affect the result stored in %var2%.

Answer (score 0):

I had quotation marks (") in the PATH variable that caused this, after I removed them it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the semicolon symbol (";") at the environment variables list can cause the same behavior on Win 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem fixed by removing spaces.