# Anaconda '\microsoft was unexpected at this time' error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

When I input conda command like `conda install` in the anaconda prompt, I have some error message

> '\microsoft was unexpected at this time'

I check double quotes or some spell error, but I could't find it.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python interpreter is installed in a directory that contain spaces and special characters, such as:  the "Program Files (x86)"

Install Anaconda in D:\myAnaconda or any other directory, whose path doesn't include space or any special character.

you may find this thread useful: [Visual Studio Command Prompt gives "\Common was unexpected at this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756828/visual-studio-command-prompt-gives-common-was-unexpected-at-this-time)

Comment: Thanks to your answer

Answer (score 2):

In conda.bat script file, at this line:

```
@for %%B in (%~dp0.) do @set PATH=...
```

adding quotation marks inside parentheses,

```
@for %%B in ("%~dp0.") do @set PATH=...
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by this problem too. But on an [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/gvanem/watt-32/builds/30308177/job/49a511rx20pb1ysi) job.

Seems the `cmd` junk have problems with parsing things like:

```
set X=y
if %X%. == y. (
  set PATH=c:\whatever;%PATH%
  ...
)
```

when `PATH` already contains a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XXX` path.

Further, having a `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XXX"` in the `PATH` does *not* help either.