# CLion can't find MSVC build tools

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have been developing c++ applications for a while now but suddenly my CLion can't find the MSVC build tools in the toolchain settings. I have tried reinstalling everything and have even tried installing Visual Studio 2019 but with no success.

Current setup:

Visual Studio 2022 build tools
Custom CMake.exe (version 3.27.5)
[image: My settings dialog]

Right now this window will keep loading forever and every now and then it will say not found on the toolset, CMake, Build Tool and both compilers. It will show a message saying my vcvarsall.bat can't be found.

The error:

Cannot load Visual C++ environment from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat:
command [C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, /c, "call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 8.1 1>&2 && C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion-Nova\ch-0\233.13309\jbr\bin\java -cp C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion-Nova\ch-0\233.13309\lib\util_rt.jar com.intellij.util.ReadEnv > C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-cmd-env-data.9705437073658366065.tmp || exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%"], exit code: 1

I have looked in the MSVC build tools folder and the vcvarsall.bat is defenitely there. How do I get CLion to find my 2022 Build Tool installation?

All steps I have taken:

- Reinstall a different version of Visual Studio
- Install the 2022 Build Tools
- Run the vcvarsall.bat in the 2022 Build Tools
- Reinstall CLion (different versions)
- Cry
- Manually set the Build Tool, C Compiler and C++ Compiler fields

Comment: I have been using CLion for over 3 years on a MSVC toolchain and never had this issue with VS Pro 2019 installed. Today suddenly I am getting the exact same issue on CLion 2023.3.3, even though it was still working fine an hour ago. No idea what suddenly changed!?

Comment: I have not been able to fix it to this day and I am not going to try either because I had to use CLion for school for just 3 months. I wish you luck and maybe the other answer on this thread can help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to calling vcvarshall.bat
E.g. in my case executing `$C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsall.bat` gives the expected argument error, but `$vcvarshall.bat x86` (or amd64 as in your case) gives a strange error "\Common was unexpected at this time.":
[image: \Common was unexpected at this time.]

Apparently it is related to a mangled Path variable: [Visual Studio Command Prompt gives "\Common was unexpected at this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756828/visual-studio-command-prompt-gives-common-was-unexpected-at-this-time)

So I suggest you try and launch vcvarshall.bat with a valid arch specified directly from a `cmd` window to debug the underlying issue